# How do I set up and use de4dot?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, deobfuscation, de4dot

I already know some geniuses are going to say if you have to ask this then you shouldn't be using it. DO NOT CARE. I have a couple of games I want to mod and port to other engines and languages for sake of performance. I was able to download the files but the binaries that most people were using instead are gone. I already have my decompiler. I am trying to pick coding and looking at high-level examples is the best way for me. I am using Visual Studio 2019 Personal.

Comment: Odd, looks like it's been archived and the releases deleted. dnSpy (same author) is also archived with [one release](https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy/releases). See also [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/kb0j1u/dnspy_archived_anyone_know_why/)

Comment: Porting someone else game to another language and engine without the source code, if that is what you are trying to do, is probably as difficult as creating the game from scratch. Not to mention illegal.

Comment: @JonasH only if I intend to sell it and I don't.